# Blazor child component event handling

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-7.0, c#-11.0

Using .Net 7 and Blazor server, I am trying to build a message viewer using a Message component and a `List<Message>` as a class library to reuse across all apps in my environment. Everything works fine except for the ability to remove the Message component from the list. The Message razor class looks like

```
@namespace TestApp.Components

@if(MessageText!=null){
    <div class="mt-3 @MessageClass">
        @MessageText
        <button class="btn-close" @onclick="CloseMessage">Close</button>
    </div>
}
```

and the relevant parts of the code behind are as such:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace TestApp.Components;
public partial class Message : ComponentBase
{
    public string MessageText {get;set;} = string.Empty;
    public string MessageClass {get;set;} = string.Empty;
    public Guid MessageId {get;set;} = new Guid();
    [Parameter] public Message Origin {set{
        MessageText=value.MessageText;
        MessageClass=value.MessageClass;
        MessageId=value.MessageId;
    }}
    public Message(){

    }
    public Message(string message){
        MessageText=message;
    }
    public event EventHandler CloseRequested=default!;

    private void CloseMessage()
    {
        CloseRequested(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This is all then referenced in an application state class that holds the list of messages per user, until they are dismissed. That code looks like

```
using TestApp.Components;

public class ApplicationState
{
    public List<Message> Messages {get;set;} = new();
    public event EventHandler OnMessagesChange = default!;

    public void AddMessage(string messageText)
    {
        var message = new Message(messageText);
        Messages.Add(message);
        EventHandler handler = OnMessagesChange;
        if(handler!=null)
            handler.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        message.CloseRequested+=RemoveMessage;
    }

    private void RemoveMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var message = (Message?)sender;
        if(message!=null)
            Messages.Remove(message);
    }
}
```

When I click the button to remove the message, I get the error `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` which I understand to mean that the EventHandler is initialized but I can't figure out *why* it isn't since the ApplicationState class subscribes to that event and therefore it should be invokable.

I've tried null checking the event handler in the `CloseMessage` method as well as setting the event handler to `=default!;` with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start at removing both `= default!`s and invoking both events in the same correct manner (`OnMessagesChange?.Invoke()`, `CloseRequested?.Invoke()`). In the process you may want to pay attention to where the debugger tells you the error is.

Comment: How do you show the messages? Because you should not `new()` something that is `: ComponentBase`

Comment: @GSerg I agree that this corrects the throw exception, however, the event still doesn't fire in the `ApplicationState` class which is what I'm trying to accomplish. I was under the impression that if I subscribe to the event (`message.CloseRequested+=RemoveMessage`) that the EventHandler should no longer be null. Am I incorrect in that?

Comment: @HH I am showing them by iterating through the list via a foreach loop in a razor page. Inside that loop, it uses the component to with the `Origin` property to set the values. I can separate those into different classes so that I'm not newing up a `ComponentBase` fairly easily, just trying to keep it simple but maybe that is causing the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
  var message = new Message(messageText); // new() of a Component
  ...
  message.CloseRequested+=RemoveMessage;
```

and

> ... a foreach loop in a razor page. Inside that loop, it uses the component to with the Origin property to set the values.

This means that you have 2 Components for each message: 1 in the list, with the event set and 1 created by the foreach loop. You copy the properties but not the event.

The instance from the foreach loop will be the one shown, and that has `eventCloseRequested == null`

The solution is to split this in a `MessageComponent : ComponentBase` and a `MessageViewModel`. Then it is at least clearer what is going on.

I leave the event handling open, there are many ways to do that. But you'll also want to update the parent page when you remove a message. So I would add an EventCallback param to the component and assign an update method on that page.

Comment: You are 100% correct. Thanks for that; I didn't even think about the fact that it newed up the class twice. I tested this (as you were writing the response probably) and with a backing model you can subscribe to the event from the ApplicationState then wire that to the event from the button. Thanks for the help.